# Many to one query with sum function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Good afternoon,

I have a table that has the following data:

```
SeqNo     OrderNo    Housebill   Miles    LineTotal
--------------------------------------------------
319265    6252       19712       379.00   35.00
319266    6252       19712       379.00   88.12
319264    6252       19712       379.00   587.45
320676    6328       24699       379.00   35.00
320677    6328       24699       379.00   88.12
320675    6328       24699       379.00   587.45
320178    6423       11824       487.00   1495.00
321710    6428       11827       668.00   1900.00
```

I am having troubles wrapping my head around a for each command. What I am looking for is for each `OrderNo` that is the same, to return one line that calculates the sum of `LineTotal` fields.

The data in the end, I would want to look like this:

```
OrderNo  Housebill   Miles   LineTotal
--------------------------------------
6252      19712      379     710.57
6328      24699      379     710.57
6423      11824      487     1495.00
6428      11827      668     1900.00
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using a simple `group by` like this:

```
SELECT OrderNo
    ,Housebill
    ,Miles
    ,cast(sum(LineTotal) AS VARCHAR(10)) AS LineTotal  
    --this is optional: casting LineTotal as string to match your output
FROM sequences
GROUP BY OrderNo
        ,Housebill
        ,Miles
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3f9e3/6/0)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! Sorry, I am quite new to SQL query building, hense me not using the aggregate function.

Comment: @DouglasSussan It's all good. We all have to start somewhere. :)